# swiftUI Button with width:0 nonetheless active

Tags: swiftui

I set the width of a SwiftUI Button to 0 to "deactivate" it.
If the with of the button is set to 0, the button disappears as expected, but clicking in the left edge of the yellow Stack activates the Button.
Why does this happen?
How can I avoid it?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var zeroWidth = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      ButtonLine( leftButtons: [ButtonAttr( label: "LB1",
                                            action: {print("LB1")},
                                            iconSystemName : "person"
                                          )],
                                 zeroWidth: zeroWidth
                  )
      Button("Toggle width \(zeroWidth ? "On" : "Off" ) "){ self.zeroWidth.toggle() }
    }
  }
}

struct ButtonLine: View {
  let leftButtons : [ButtonAttr]
  let zeroWidth : Bool

  var body: some View {

    HStack(spacing: 0) {
      ForEach(leftButtons.indices, id: \.self)
      { i in
        HStack(spacing: 0.0)
        {
          Button(action: { self.leftButtons[i].action() }) {
            ButtonLabel( singleline: false,
                         buttonAttr: self.leftButtons[i]
            )
            .padding(0)
            //.background(Color.green)  // not visible
          }
         .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .frame( width: self.zeroWidth ? 0 : 100, height: 50) 
         .background(Color.green)
         .clipped()
         .foregroundColor(Color.white)
         .padding(0)
        }
        // .background(Color.blue)   // not visible
      }
      // .background(Color.blue)   // not visible
      Spacer()
      Text("CONTENT")
      .background(Color.green)
      .onTapGesture {
        print("Content tapped")
      }
      Spacer()
    }
    .background(Color.yellow)
      .onTapGesture {
        print("HS tapped")
    }
  }
}

struct ButtonLabel: View {
  var singleline : Bool
  var buttonAttr : ButtonAttr
  var body: some View {
    VStack (spacing: 0.0) {
      Image(systemName: buttonAttr.iconSystemName).frame(height: singleline ? 0 : 20).clipped()
      .padding(0)
      .background(Color.blue)
      Text(buttonAttr.label)
      .padding(0)
      .background(Color.blue)
    }
    .padding(0)
    .background(Color.red)
  }
}

struct ButtonAttr
{   let label : String
    let action: ()-> Void
    let iconSystemName : String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable you Button by adding a `.disabled(self.zeroWidth)`

```
Button(action: { self.leftButtons[i].action() }) {
    ButtonLabel( singleline: false,
                buttonAttr: self.leftButtons[i]
    )
        .padding(0)
       //.background(Color.green)  // not visible
}
.disabled(self.zeroWidth)
.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
.frame( width: self.zeroWidth ? 0 : 100, height: 50)
.background(Color.green)
.clipped()
.foregroundColor(Color.white)
.padding(0)
```

[image]

You can debug the view hierarchy by clicking that icon in xcode: 
[image]

Comment: Thnx! Also a good solution, but for my understanding, do you know, what's the reason, why the 0-width-button is still active?

Comment: @mica because its still part of the view hierarchy. I did edit my post to show the view hierarchy and to show you how to debug it yourself. Why it is still part of the hierarchy even thou it has no width, I dont know.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of tricky "deactivate", just use real remove, like below

```
    HStack(spacing: 0.0)
    {
        if !self.zeroWidth {
            Button(action: { self.leftButtons[i].action() }) {
                ButtonLabel( singleline: false,
                             buttonAttr: self.leftButtons[i]
                )
                    .padding(0)
                //.background(Color.green)  // not visible
            }
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            .background(Color.green)
            .clipped()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(0)
        }
    }.frame(height: 50) // to keep height persistent
```

Comment: Thnx! good solution, I will use it, but for my understanding: what's the reason, why the 0-width-button is still active?

Comment: @mica, we don't know internal implementation of SwiftUI, but 0-width might not remove tracking rect, so active element handling events is still present. Anyway... such things are no reliable, even if it would work now, it might stop in next version, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

there is very simple explanation.

try next snippet

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello").padding().border(Color.yellow).fixedSize().frame(width: 0)
    }
}
```

[image]

Why?

```
.frame(..)
```

is defined as a function of View, which return another View, as any kind of View modifier. The resulting View has .zero sized frame, as expected.

It is really true? Let's check it!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            Text("Hello")
                .padding()
                .border(Color.black)
                .fixedSize()
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .blendMode(.exclusion)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Just add .clipped modifier to your Text View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            Text("Hello")
                .padding()
                .border(Color.black)
                .fixedSize()
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .clipped()
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .blendMode(.exclusion)
        }
    }
}
```

and the Text "disappears[image]" ...

It disappears from the screen, but not from View hierarchy!. Change the code again

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            Text("Hello")
                .padding()
                .border(Color.black)
                .fixedSize().onTapGesture {
                    print("tap")
                }
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .clipped()
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .blendMode(.exclusion)
        }
    }
}
```

and you see, that there is still some "invisible" area sensitive on tap gesture

[image]